# use set language in a sql function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, date-formatting

I want to use `DATENAME` in a function, but the problem is datename's result is dependent on login or install language setup.

to make sure all the time it return english result I need to use `set language 'English'` but if I use it inside a function I will get following error

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SET COMMAND' within a function.

Comment: You can't. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but the main reason I can see for using `DATENAME` is to provide some formatting of a date, which is a job for the presentation layer not SQL. If I am mistaken, and there is a genuine need for knowing an english date name, then your best option is to create a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), and add columns with the English date name for each date, then use that in your function.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using SQL Server 2012 or newer, this is very easy to do via the `FORMAT` function, as shown here:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE 'English';

DECLARE @TestDate DATETIME;
SET @TestDate = '2015-06-23';

SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd'); -- Tuesday
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'en-us'); -- Tuesday
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'ru-RU'); -- вторник
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'fa-IR'); -- سه شنبه

SET LANGUAGE 'French';

SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd'); -- mardi
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'en-us'); -- Tuesday
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'ru-RU'); -- вторник
SELECT FORMAT(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'fa-IR'); -- سه شنبه
```

But what about anyone still using SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2? Well, the same can be accomplished using SQLCLR. And in fact, the `FORMAT` function that was introduced in SQL Server 2012 (i.e. the one shown above), is using SQLCLR behind the scenes. So you can either write a simple CLR UDF to do this, or you can simply download the [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library (which I am the author of, but this function is available in the Free version) and use the `Date_Format` function, as shown here:

```sql
SET LANGUAGE 'English';

DECLARE @TestDate DATETIME;
SET @TestDate = '2015-06-23';

SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', ''); -- Tuesday
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'en-us'); -- Tuesday
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'ru-RU'); -- вторник
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'fa-IR'); -- سه شنبه

SET LANGUAGE 'French';

SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', ''); -- Tuesday (Windows lang, not SQL Server's)
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'en-us'); -- Tuesday
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'ru-RU'); -- вторник
SELECT SQL#.Date_Format(@TestDate, 'dddd', 'fa-IR'); -- سه شنبه
```

The SQL# `Date_Format` function has essentially the same signature as the built-in `FORMAT` function, except that the 3rd parameter (Culture) cannot be omitted in a SQLCLR function, so when not using a culture it would need to be set to an empty string `''`. Another difference is that SQLCLR does not seem to be aware of the current session `LANGUAGE` setting, so the default culture is whatever Windows is set to (but that is specifically a non-issue in this particular case).

P.S. See the MSDN page for [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more formatting options.

Comment: This option is supported only SQL 2012 and above but this question is published under SQL 2008.

Comment: @AnandaKumarJayaraman Yes, the question is concerning SQL Server 2008, which I specifically addressed and even gave an example that works in SQL Server 2005, 2008, and 2008 R2. I added the info about the `FORMAT` function for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```sql
select  
  case datepart(dw,getdate())
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 1) % 7,0),7)  then 'Sunday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 2) % 7,0),7) then 'Monday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 3) % 7,0),7) then 'Tuesday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 4) % 7,0),7) then 'Wednesday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 5) % 7,0),7) then 'Thursday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 6) % 7,0),7) then 'Friday'
  when  isnull(nullif((7- @@datefirst + 7) % 7,0),7) then 'Saturday'
end;
```

Comment: This suffers from the exact same problem that the OP is already trying to account for: language-based settings. The `@@DATEFIRST`  value is based upon the current language and hence will change with different `SET LANGUAGE` values, just like `DATENAME` output does. Please see the MSDN page for [@@DATEFIRST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187766.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Before commenting anything, please put a try and then comment. Read the code completely and then write your comment.

Comment: I had tested, but not the entire query including the `DATEPART()` function, which I had forgotten was also sensitive to the value of `@@DATEFIRST`. So yes, this does appear to work. Sorry for not being more thorough in my test. I tried to remove the downvote but it gave me an error saying that it was locked unless the answer is edited. So if you make a minor edit, I should be able to remove the downvote.

Comment: For some reason your edit didn't register so I made a minor code-formatting change and was then able to change the downvote to an upvote.